# After running docker version the below error is reflecting while every thing has done properly

Tags: docker

cannot connect to the docker demon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker demon running?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your docker service is stopped. Try to start the docker `sudo service docker start`.